# TclOO : Get base object from another class

Tags: tcl

I have 2 classes `fruit` and `orange`, my goal is to get the *object* that allowed me to build my `fruit` class.

```
namespace eval test {}

oo::class create test::fruit {

    constructor {type} {
        if {$type eq "orange"} {
            set orange [test::orange new]
        }
    }
    
    destructor {
        puts "[self] destroy..."
    }
}

oo::class create test::orange {

    constructor {} {
    }
    
    destructor {
        puts "[self] destroy..."
    }
}

set f [test::fruit new "orange"]
```

I found a solution to find the base object (`from class ::test::fruit`) by saving my `orange` variable in a global variable `baseobject` like this :

```
oo::class create test::fruit {

    variable baseobject

    constructor {type} {
        if {$type eq "orange"} {
            set orange [test::orange new]
            set baseobject $orange
            
        }
    }

    method baseclass {} {
        return $baseobject
    }
}
```

Is there any command, another solution ? I don't know if my way, is oriented object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here. You can use `info object` and `info class` to get all the relationships that the TclOO system knows about; they literally read the information out of the underlying C structures that power the whole system.

In particular:

- `info class instances Foo` gets the instances of the class `Foo`.
- `info class subclasses Foo` gets the (direct) subclasses of the class `Foo`.
- `info class superclasses Foo` gets the (direct) superclasses of the class `Foo`. This will be `::oo::object` if you haven't said otherwise; *all* classes have that as an ultimate superclass.
- `info object class bar` gets the class of the object `bar`.

```
oo::class create Foo
oo::class create Foo2 {superclass Foo}
Foo create bar

puts [info class instances Foo];    # => ::bar
puts [info class subclasses Foo];   # => ::Foo2
puts [info class superclasses Foo]; # => ::oo::object
puts [info object class bar];       # => ::Foo
```

If the relationship between the objects and classes is not one of the standard ones, you'll have to capture that yourself; there are several ways, and you already know one of the easy ones, i.e., keeping the name in an instance variable somehow.

Also remember that all classes are themselves instances of their metaclass, which is called `oo::class` (or one of its subclasses). This means that you can use `info object class Foo` to get the class that created `Foo`. Yes, this means that `oo::class` is an instance of itself; its construction (and that of `oo::object`) is *special*.

---

If you want to arrange for an object to be *owned* by another object, i.e., to be automatically destroyed when the owner object is destroyed, the simplest way is to make the name of the owned object be in the owner's instance namespace (the `create` method of `oo::object` is namespace aware when resolving what you mean by the name you give it), and then it will be automatically destroyed when the owner goes, with no need for explicit destruction.

```
method makeMyOrange args {
    test::orange create myOrange {*}$args
}
```

If you only have a fixed set of owned objects, giving them the names you prefer in your instance namespace is trivial. Otherwise, a simple instance-local counter for generating names is also trivial:

```
method makeOneOfMyOranges args {
    variable counter
    test::orange create myOrange[incr counter] {*}$args
}
```

Note that the `new` method of `oo::object` makes names that aren't owned that way. (Or rather, it makes names that are owned by TclOO itself.)

---

If you want some other random otherwise-unrelated object to know about who made it, pass `[self]` as an argument to the constructor.

```
oo::class create test::orange {
    constructor {maker} {
        puts "I was made by $maker"
    }
}

oo::class create test::fruit {
    constructor {} {
        set orange [test::orange new [self]]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks It was my second question ? If I destroy my object `::test::fruit` , `::test::orange` will be automatically destroyed ? I will look at your answer in detail

Comment: finally... to do simple , I create a class by another... and is there a relation between both ? I keep reading your answer...